# Can I add free trial period to subscription which already approved and in production(iTunes Connect)?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, subscription

iTunes Connect/IOS
We have issue like we are in production and have auto renewable subscription. We want to add free trial period for week, can we add this to already created subscription(and it in production), I know that we can do it before review. Please, tell us what you know about it, we will appreciate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:
iTunes Connect -> 
My Apps -> 
Features -> 
In-App Purchases -> 
the Subscription you want to change -> 
Subscription Prices + (click + icon)  -> 
Set up introductory Price ->
Set Territories for Introductory Price (You can just click Next) ->
Set Introductory Price Start/End Date (You can choose 'No End Date' if you want) and click Next ->

Set Type of Introductory Price : Free trial and set duration ->

Remember to Save !!!